# Amazon AMI uploading database

Tags: file-upload, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to work out how to upload a 15gb database to my Amazon AMI on EC2. It keeps dropping. My ISP gives 1.5mb/s upload. Also my download speed is goes to neraly nothing when I am uploading. Is there a way to send the database over quickly using EC2?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using `rsync` with options like:

```
rsync -PazSHAX LOCALDIRECTORY/ REMOTEHOST:/REMOTEDIRECTORY/
```

Keep running it until it completes successfully as it will resume where it left off.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any database GUI manager to upload the database. Connect to your EC2 database  using your database GUI manager and upload the data from your local system. If you are using MySQL as your database I will suggest [SQLYog](http://www.webyog.com/en/) MySQL GUI manager, Connect to your EC2 using ssh tunneling and upload your data.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider [Amazon Import/Export](http://aws.amazon.com/importexport/) for that. It costs some money, though.